# Liquibase precondition for unique constraint

Tags: sql, liquibase, preconditions

I want to add a unique constraint to a column using Liquibase. Of course I want to check if duplicate rows exist using a precondition.

I came up this:

```
<preConditions>
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">
        select count(*)
        from person
        having ( count(username) > 1 )
    </sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
```

However this produces `Empty set` on MySQL and probably other databases.

I tried using `expectedResult=""` and `expectedResult="null"` but both don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always force a result:

```
select 
  case when exists(
    select username, count(*)
    from person
    group by username
    having count(*) > 1 )
    then 1
    else 0
  end
```

This also allows a more normal group by/having

Comment: Thanks, works on MySQL. Does this work on other databases like MSSQL/Oracle/HSQL?

Comment: This query will work on all databases (I composed it that way because you didn't tag your question with a specific database)

Comment: Super! Really appreciate it ;-)